# Is a traditional Yekke Sargenes similar to the Skver style, all-linen, non-embroidered Kittel? I think so; I'm not sure about the "hood", though

Tags: minhag, yekke, kittel, german

Below is a link where one can view a
[Skver/New Square Style Kittel for sale](https://malbushikovod.com/products/kittel-67110-sqwere-stile-100-linen-big-collar-closed-front-no-tucks-no-lace)

Comment: Just be careful about shatnez. Chassidim can wear linen kittels because their shabbos bekeshes are not wool.

Comment: I am unaware that wearing individual garments of wool and linen presents a problem of shatnez.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.300.4?with=Commentary&lang=bi
See Ramma here with Tax Be'r Heitev etc.

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Thankfully, we are noheg today to do so (as cited from Teshuvos haRashba).

Answer (score 2):

In K'hal Adath Jeshurun, Washington Heights (commonly known as Breuer's) the mimetic tradition in the kehilloh (congregation) indicates that the Skverer kittel is "closest" to the old, German-style Sargenes, although I believe that there are some differences. Being more than 80 years separated from our old German kehillos (congregations), there is a chance that mimetic usage may not be 100% correct, but this is what is used by the medakdikim (punctilious), today.